# Calling variable value in Magento

Tags: php, magento, html

I am having a little trouble calling a variable value in Magento.

I want to display a new message to the customer if a product's availability stock status is **limited stock** in the product page, right under the availability stock status.

So I think to myself here goes nothing:

> /public_html/app/design/frontend/mytheme/default/template/catalog/product/view.phtml

```
<?php if ( $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('stoc')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product) = 'stoc limitat' : ?>
<?php echo '<div id="nota.produs"> Nota : Va rugam verificati telefonic disponibilitatea acestui produs.   </div>' ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Rolling up my sleeves happily, save, upload, refresh but the product page does not load anything right.

I get it, I'm not calling the value the right way, am I?

Thanks.

P.S. Sorry if this is a stupidly simple matter. (I'm not the brightest light bulb in the ceiling when it comes to Magento, or for that matter PHP all together)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php if ($_product->getAttributeText('stoc') == 'stoc limitat') : ?>
```

Comment: could you please post the output of `$_product->getAttributeText('stoc')`?

Comment: yahoo .. 10x a million oleg, this is the second time you saved me. I'm starting to owe a truckload of bear. :))

Comment: ok then a truckload of beer, and i'll add the bear as a bonus ( you know as a drinking buddy). Really thanks again!!